# How to calculate hours greater than 24h using datejs

Tags: javascript, time, datejs

In table I have field type TIME where I am storing time interval e.g. 92:30:00, what I am trying to do with javascript (datejs) is to add or remove e.g. 02:15:00 to/from 92:30:00.

I am able to do it when the hours are not greater than 23:59 but how to do it when the values are over 23:59?

```
grab a from db //as 92:30
var b = Date.parse(a);
var c = Date.parse("02:15");

    d= new TimeSpan(b-c);
    e= (b).addHours(c);

console.log(d.toString("HH:mm")
console.log(e.toString("HH:mm")
```

as I sad it works If you stay in 24h time range, could it be possible to do the same with greater hours interval?

UPDATE: 
(sum them)

```
t = Date.today();
cc = Date.parse(c);
dd = Date.parse(d);

ccc = (cc - t)
ddd = (dd - t);

res = new TimeSpan(ccc+ddd);
console.log(res.toString()); //3.22:45:00
```

Comment: What is then end value you would like based on your numbers provided above? Remember Dates and Times are always relative to a point in time. What is '92:30:00' relative to? Is that 92 hours and 30 minutes from 'now' or 00:00:00 (midnight)? or based on another point in time. Date.parse is going to assume 'midnight' is your starting point.

Comment: it's just time interval, something like "how menu hours you spend this week helping people", kind of time tracking

Comment: Can you fix your code samples so they demonstrate the whole scenario, instead of taking pieces from one and pieces from another. It's very confusion trying to figure out what the final result should be. So now you want a string value representing the days-hours-minutes-seconds?

Comment: First, Thank you for your help... sum is ok, I make it works,  I will just convert this string to hours (d,h,m > h,m)  and it's what do I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Datejs is going to parse a >24 hour time value correctly. The easiest work-around I can think of is just splitting the string into its parts and adding to `Date.today()`.

Here's a sample demonstrating the whole scenario.

**Example**

```
var a = '92:30'.split(':');
var b = '02:15'.split(':');

var c = Date.today().addHours(+a[0]).addMinutes(+a[1]);
var d = Date.today().addHours(+b[0]).addMinutes(+b[1]);

var e = new TimeSpan(c - d);

console.log('days', e.days);  // 3
console.log('hours', e.hours);  // 18
console.log('minutes', e.minutes);  // 15
```

I'm not 100% what you would like as an end result, but once you have the `e` TimeSpan you have the product of subtracting the two original values.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**: If you just want to do simple math on the value to calculate an hours value, the following should work.

**Example**

```
var a = '92:30'.split(':');
var b = '02:15'.split(':');

var c = Date.today().addHours(+a[0]).addMinutes(+a[1]);
var d = Date.today().addHours(+b[0]).addMinutes(+b[1]);

var diff = (c - d) / (1000 * 60 * 60);

console.log(diff); // 90.25
```

You shouldn't require Datejs to do this though. Just using the native JavaScript Date API is all you need and you could remove any of Datejs API from the above sample.

Comment: hmm, actually second solution is not what do I need, instead of 90.25 should be 90:15...I have updated first post with sum solution, could you please take a look, is it ok like that?

Comment: 90.25 is correct. If you want .25 of an hour to be represented as minutes-of-an-hour (15), then you should be able to easily convert.

Answer (score 1):

Not a bad attempt, but you forgot that the **ZERO** date is actually 1 Jan 1970 (I think). So, you will need to do date arithmetics with that in mind.

Comment: that shouldn't be the issue as the datejs, timejs take a care about that, problem is how to parse 92:30 ;)